# My python websocket connection doesn't seem to be receiving any messages

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I have this code for a game i'm making:

```
async def ws(websocket, path):

    connected.append(websocket)

    try:
        while True:
            if(running == 0):
                asyncio.ensure_future(main_loop(websocket, path))
            recivedData = await websocket.recv()  
            parsedData = json.loads(recivedData)
            print(parsedData)
    finally:

        connected.remove(websocket)
```

In this code, main_loop is responsible for sending messages at a constant rate. But await websocket.recv()  doesn't seem to be receiving anything. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I can't see the whole of the code, but I think you might be using a regular TCP/IP socket, since you don't seem to "unwrap" WebSocket frames or handle WebSocket protocol details. I assume you're silently failing because of the JSON parser throwing exceptions inside the `try` section.

Comment: @Myst, i'm using the python websocket library, and I don't see anything about unwrapping in the docs. However, the JSON idea is still possible; How would I test if the JSON is making errors? I have had no past issues with JSON in python.

Comment: @Myst I ruled out the JSON idea, I tried printing recivedData directly without JSON - it did not print.